# How to put a conditional in a scope on mustachio for postmark template

Tags: templates, mustache, email-templates, postmark

I can't find a solution for this problem I have a template like this (all my trades are managed with balises like this in my template):

```
{{french}}Bonjour{{/french}}{{english}}Hello{{/english}}
```

I want to add a conditional balise in each trad balise like this:

```
{{french}}Bonjour {{^isToday}}demain{{/isToday}}{{/french}}{{english}}Hello{{^isToday}}tomorrow{{/isToday}}{{/english}}
```

But the data template model I send to the api is something like this:

```
{
  french: true,
  isToday: true,
}
```

Mustachio wants my "`isToday`" to be in the french object I'm a bit lost I also tried to up one level in my scope but it doesn't work:

```
{{french}}Bonjour {{^../isToday}}demain{{/isToday}}{{/french}}
```

Any idea please ?

Regards,

Comment: Mustachio is not the same as Handlebars.

Comment: It is also not the same as Mustache. Have you tried `{{^../isToday}}demain{{/../isToday}}`? In Mustache, the content of the closing tag should match the opening tag exactly, so maybe they preserved that rule in Mustachio.